# Android TableLayout/TableRow: how do I get uniform row heights when I'm "shrinking" a column?

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout which is specified in the XML, to which I add TableRows programmatically. I have to add the rows this way because I do not know the structure of the table (i.e., number of columns, etc...) until run time.

Initially, I was having a problem with the table extending off the right end of the page when there was enough data in the rows.  Now I am shrinking the final column, which wraps the text in that column and causes the table to be entirely visible.  However, I now have a problem where the shunk column is "taller" than the other cells it the row, which looks ugly.  Here is a screen shot:

**Well, apparently I'm not allowed to post an image because I do not have "10 reputation points".**

I'm not sure how to get my problem across without the image.  If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate that.

Here is the XML that defines the TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/boilingPoint"
    style="@style/PhysicalPropertyTable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And here is the code snippet that get the table and specifies the column to shrink:

```
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(tableLayoutID);       
layout.setColumnShrinkable(shrinkIndex, true);
```

What can I do so that the height of each cell in the row is the same as the tallest row?

Thanks in advance for any help.